# Minify jspm bundle with Angular2 breaks ngModel

Tags: bundle, angular, minify, uglifyjs, jspm

I have a problem with my angular2 project. I use jspm to manage dependencies and bundle files. When I minify my bundle any ngModel stops working. I created simple gist to demonstrate my problem: https://gist.github.com/mlewando/861218f572790bc1204a to run it enter:

```
npm install
npm run jspm
npm run build
npm run start
```

This will build my simple app, bundle it into dist/libs.js and start lite server. In this scenario everything works as expected. Then when you enter

```
npm run break
```

You'll end up with nimified libs.js and in browsers console you'll see "No value accessor for '' in [test in e@2:29]".

Any idea what do to to fix this?